# How to add variable to src attribute

Tags: angularjs

I have img tag

```
<img src='http://...../{{element}}'/>
```

and i have error

> /%7B%7element%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)

How in `angular.js` add a variable to the `src` attribute?

Comment: FYI the `%7B` and `%7D` are caused by URL encoding the braces. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-src` so that the browser doesn't attempt to download the resource before AngularJs has re-rendered the DOM.

```
<img ng-src='http://...../{{element}}'/>
```